# Unable to hide graph while exporting to excel

Tags: reporting-services

I am working a report in SSRS. that has two sections one is graph and other is Table.
client should able to see both Graph and table on reporting manager but when exported only the table should get exported to excel. Please let me know how to achieve this.Please find the below screenshot. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJOoW.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Hidden property of anything you want to hide to an expression. If you base this on the renderformat you can hide things depending on what format you export in.

This was introduced in 2008R2 so I'm assuming you are not using an earlier version.

Set the 'Hidden' property of the chart or it's container to

```
=NOT(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteracive)
```

This should hide the chart when it's redndered to any other format.

Read this for more details

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/built-in-collections-built-in-globals-and-users-references-report-builder?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

For the chart, you set the Hidden expression to not show if the format is Excel.

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCELOPENXML", False, True)
```